# deriving a Functor for an infinite Stream

Tags: haskell, functor, recursive-datastructures

I'm following this [blog](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/28/f-algebras/) about F-algebras
It explains that

> A terminal coalgebra is usually interpreted in programming as a recipe
>   for generating (possibly infinite) data structures or transition
>   systems.

and says  that

> A canonical example of a coalgebra is based on a functor whose fixed
>   point is an infinite stream of elements of type e. This is the
>   functor:

```
data StreamF e a = StreamF e a
  deriving Functor
```

and this is its fixed point:

```
data Stream e = Stream e (Stream e)
```

I’ve tried the code [here](https://repl.it/repls/FeistyActualBrownbutterfly)

the relevant part being

```
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
unFix :: Fix f -> f (Fix f)
unFix (Fix x) = x

cata :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata alg = alg . fmap (cata alg) . unFix

ana :: Functor f => (a -> f a) -> a -> Fix f
ana coalg = Fix . fmap (ana coalg) . coalg

data StreamF e a = StreamF e a
    deriving Functor
data Stream e = Stream e (Stream e)

era :: [Int] -> StreamF Int [Int]
era (p : ns) = StreamF p (filter (notdiv p) ns)
    where notdiv p n = n `mod` p /= 0

primes = ana era [2..]
```

I’m getting this error

```
main.hs:42:14: error:
• Can’t make a derived instance of ‘Functor (StreamF e)’:
You need DeriveFunctor to derive an instance for this class
• In the data declaration for ‘StreamF’
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can't use `deriving (Functor)` in vanilla Haskell. You need the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` at the top of your file. More info [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/DeriveFunctor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deriving` is very limited in Haskell without using language extensions. Since the compiler can't always work out what a `Functor` instance should be, `deriving Functor` is not standard Haskell.

However, there is a language extension that allows this, namely `-XDeriveFunctor`. To enable this extension do one of:

- Compile with the flag `-XDeriveFunctor`. (Eg: run `ghc -XDeriveFunctor Main.hs` when compiling)
- Write the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` at the top of your file.

Here's how your file would look with this pragma added:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
unFix :: Fix f -> f (Fix f)
unFix (Fix x) = x

cata :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata alg = alg . fmap (cata alg) . unFix

ana :: Functor f => (a -> f a) -> a -> Fix f
ana coalg = Fix . fmap (ana coalg) . coalg

data StreamF e a = StreamF e a
    deriving Functor
data Stream e = Stream e (Stream e)

era :: [Int] -> StreamF Int [Int]
era (p : ns) = StreamF p (filter (notdiv p) ns)
    where notdiv p n = n `mod` p /= 0

primes = ana era [2..]
```

If you plan on using GHCi, use `:set -XDeriveFunctor` before loading the file.

Comment: Rather, the compiler *can* derive a `Functor` instance (it's fairly trivial to do so), it just isn't *required* to do so in Haskell 2010.